# Sizing / Layout directives in Angular which depends on other directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am quite new in Angular and have the following question about sizing / layouts.

Imagine you have custom directives of this sort:

In the scenario above, imagine you want `<main-ui>` to take the entire viewport width and height, and the `<content-ui>` would take the entire viewport width and height but reducing the `<header-ui>` height.

What approach would you take through Angular to make sure that the `<content-ui>` height is always as requested, both initially and on window resize?

- Should `<content-ui>` calculate its height on its own by referencing the `window` and the `<header-ui>` and performing calculations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

not related to angular i think.
i would create a css class for header and for content and define the heights, display and so on... there.
in your case maybe absolute position with top 0 for header and height 40px, and top 40px for content (numbers are as an example).
so you got

```
<main-ui>
<header-ui class="app-header"></header-ui>
<content-ui class="app-content"></content-ui>
</main-ui>
```

Comment: Similar to the comment left on @Enzey's question.. Yes I am aware of CSS techniques, but my question in learning Angular is what if I want to do such functionality using Angular? What is the best practice / approach one should take?"

Answer (score 0):

sagie gur-ari is correct, this is not related to Angular at all. All you need to use is CSS.

```css
html, body, .viewport {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.viewport {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
 flex-shrink: 0 !important;
 flex-grow: 0 !important;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

As to how to add this to functionality via a directive you would set the CSS class in the compile function of the directive.

```
module.directive('appHeader', function() {
    return {
        compile: function ($element, $attrs) {
            $element.addClass('appHeader');
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

                },
                post: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of CSS techniques, but my question in learning Angular is what if I want to do such functionality using Angular? What is the best practice / approach one should take?

Comment: In the compile function you would add the CSS class to the element the directive is on.

Comment: No, in the sense that rather than performing the calculations through CSS flexbox, I want to do such calculations using Angular Javascript calculations, i.e. calculate and set the width / height of the items initially and on every window resize.